# HTML form with lists generated thru Javascript using onchange event - not working as expected

Tags: javascript, json

I have a HTML form with a `#List1`, `#Text1` and `#List2`. `#List1` is generated through JSON via PHP from MySQL. `#Text1` changes on user input. `#List2` should also be generated through JSON from MySQL every time the user changes `#Text1`, using both the value selected in `#List1` AND the contents of `#Text1`.

The data from the form is further used in PHP to generate a table with data via a query to MySQL.

I tried to use the `onchange()` event  to generate `#List2`, **but it doesn't work** - `#List2` remains empty after user input in `#Text1`, although the `onchange()` function is executed.

HTML

```
<div class="input_frm">
  <form method="post" action="<?php print data_clean($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <table class="input_tbl">
       <tr>
          <td class="a">Select county</td>
          <td class="b"><select id="selJudet" name="Alfa" onchange="judetChg()"></select></td>
          <td class="c"><input class="button_face" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
          </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="a">Search zone as</td>
          <td class="b"><input type="text" id="selText" name="Beta" maxlength="35" placeholder="Wildcard string" onchange="textChg()" /></td>
          <td class="c"></td>
          </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="a">Select zone</td>
          <td class="b"><select id="selZona" name="Gamma" onchange="zonaChg()"></select></td>
          <td class="c"></td>
          </tr>
       </table>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function()
   {
   $.getJSON("/scripts/033A_GetJudet.php", success = function(data)
      {
      var str_options = "";
      for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
          {
          str_options += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
          }

      $("#selJudet").append(str_options);

      var selOption = document.getElementById("selJudet");
      selOption.selectedIndex = localStorage.getItem("selJudIndex") || 0;
      document.getElementById("selJudet").selectedIndex = selOption.selectedIndex;

      });

});


function judetChg() 
{
var selOption = document.getElementById("selJudet");
localStorage.setItem("selJudIndex", selOption.selectedIndex);
}

function textChg() 
{
var selTextValue = document.getElementById("selText").value;
localStorage.setItem("selTextValue", selTextValue);

var selJudet = localStorage.getItem("selJudIndex");
//alert(selJudet);

var str_http = "/scripts/033B_GetJudetWildcdZona.php?judet=" + selJudet + "&textwildcd=" + selTextValue;
//alert(str_http);

$.getJSON(str_http, success = function(data)
    {
    var str_options = "";
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
        str_options += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
        }

    $("#selZona").html("");
    $("#selZona").append(str_options);

    });

}

function zonaChg() 
{
var selOption = document.getElementById("selZona");
localStorage.setItem("selZonaIndex", selOption.selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my original text's format shortcomings. The next one will be better :).

Answer (score 0):

**It works !** And now it seems very natural, considering it is based on events. (Just like in Visual Studio - only much harder to debug :)). The code might be improved to fire also on `#List1.change` - or not, depending on the logic of the form.

I had a single error in my PHP code, a `$row['...']` variable which had an erroneous index which I did not notice, the error being there **exactly because I copied the code from another script so as not to make mistakes !**